# Flutter run show previous debugprint?

Tags: flutter

when i'm running flutter run again it will show previous debug print idk why?
can i fix it?
i want to make print clear for new run

even if i unplug my device it still print previous print

also i already did flutter clean and invalidate cache / restart

this is flutter doctor -v

flutter doctor -v

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.1184], locale en-ID)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at C:\datac\flutter
    • Framework revision 27321ebbad (3 weeks ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
    • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Ethel\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 40.2.2
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Redmi 4A • 7effb4f17ce4 • android-arm64 • Android 7.1.2 (API 25)

• No issues found!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not affect the functionality of the app you are building. It has to do with flutter `hot reload feature`. If you do a cold PC reboot and do `flutter run`, after the build process is completed and the app gets installed on your device, you can notice a spinner in your IDE saying "`Syncing files to device deviceName...`" (This happens once). This process moves files to your device memory which helps in hot-reload. To clear the log, you need to delete those files. And easy but not necessarily a fast way to clear the debugprint will be to:

> `Reboot your android device or emulator`  This will clear the memory

or

> Use another android device/emulator for testing